# Let P denote the set of all polynomials in the real variable x which varies over the interval [0, 1]. What is the closure of P in C[0, 1]

Tags: general-topology

Let P denote the set of all polynomials in the real variable x which varies
over the interval [0, 1]. What is the closure of P in C[0, 1] (with its usual supnorm
topology)

please help. no idea how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Look up the [Stone-Weierstrass Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) (For your problem, the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem suffices.)